# Looking for the name of a Peruvian dish

Tags: food-identification

I used to work with two people from Peru.  One day, they brought in a dish that they called "Planta", although I think that just referred to the fact that it had a lot of mashed plantain in it. What I remember from it is that there was a base of mashed plantain, and I think it was fried into a patty of some kind.  On top of it was ground meat and vegetables.  It was quite good, but searching for "planta" yields basically nothing.  The closest I've found seems to be "Majado de Verde", but that seems to be a vegetarian dish that's for breakfast.  This was definitely a lunch/dinner thing.  It also had a nice sauce with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it could be (beef) mofongo. (Mofongo can be made with beef, chicken, shrimp, pork, etc.)

Comment: It could be,  that at least looks similar but it seems to be from a different region

Comment: True regarding the region. Are you sure it was a Peruvian dish? I mean, even though they were from Peru, it's entirely possible that they learned to cook dishes from other regions.

Comment: Maybe not.  They mentioned that they "ate it back home", but that doesn't mean that it's a Peruvian dish I suppose.  It does look very similar...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're describing tacacho, but those are usually balls. It could be patacones, but those are more typical of Colombia